# Setting up a CNN network in keras?

Tags: python-2.7, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to implement a cnn network, which can map an input to an output.

The input consist of stft of audio files, and the output is a feature vector.

Due to the different length of audio files, will the number of total samples always be different, but each sample has a frame length of 25 ms and 10 ms overlap. shape(x,2050)

The output is a feature vector shape is (x,13).

I thought the use of cnn seemed appropriate here as the stft as the each input contains some information of the previous  sample due to the overlap.

Is it possible in keras to design a model, which make use of this, so the there will be calculated a convolutional sum for each row of the matrix, and somehow make it aware of the 25 frame length and the 10 overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, see line 220 of this file [1]. This is an implementation of Wavenet in Keras using convolutions. Even though they've created wrapper layers, this should give you the intuition on how to model audio samples.

[1] https://github.com/basveeling/wavenet/blob/master/wavenet.py#L220

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. i am not sure if the belongs to you.. but could you elaborate a bit on the implementation?